# Sqlite how to select other row if result for one is null

Tags: sqlite, select

I have a table "animal" that lists several animals each of them has an *animal_id*, a *locale*, and a *name* that corresponds to the locale, *name* can be null. The table can look like:

```
--------------------------------------------
id    |  animal_id   | locale    | name
--------------------------------------------
"4"   |   "10-3-5"   |   "en_US" |   "dog"
"5"   |   "10-3-5"   |   "de_DE" |   "hund"
"8"   |   "10-3-7"   |   "en_US" |   "fox"
"9"   |   "10-3-7"   |   "de_DE" |   NULL
```

I want to have all names for a particular *locale*, but some animal do not ever have a *name* for a particular *locale* (as above the *name* for fox is null for *locale* = de_DE), so the following sql:

```
SELECT 
    animal.animal_id,
    animal.name
FROM animal 
WHERE animal.locale = "de_DE";
```

gives

```
------------------------
animal_id  |   name 
------------------------
"10-3-5"   |   "hund"
"10-3-7"   |   NULL
```

In case a *name* is null for a particular *locale* I want to retrieve the *name* for en_US locale, the result I want is:

```
------------------------
animal_id  |   name 
------------------------
"10-3-5"   |   "hund"
"10-3-7"   |   "fox"
```

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT 
animal.animal_id,
IFNULL(animal.name, (SELECT animal.name FROM animal WHERE animal.locale="en_US"))
FROM animal 
WHERE animal.locale = "de_DE";
```

but the result is not correct and I actually do not understand it:

```
------------------------
animal_id  |   IFNULL(animal.name, (SELECT animal.name FROM animal WHERE animal.locale="en_US")) 
------------------------
"10-3-5"   |   "hund"
"10-3-7"   |   "dog"        <-- animal_id = 10-3-7 does not corresponds to "dog"
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT
animal.animal_id,
animal.name
FROM animal WHERE ((animal.locale = "de_DE" AND animal.name != NULL) 
                    OR  animal.locale = "en_US");
```

Then only *name* for *locale* equal to en_US are returned:

```
------------------------
animal_id  |   name 
------------------------
"10-3-5"   |   "dog"    
"10-3-7"   |   "fox"
```

How can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't know enough SQL flavors to know if this will help, but it looks relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6213431/2988730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track:

```
    SELECT 
        animal.animal_id,
        IFNULL(animal.name, (SELECT b.name FROM animal b WHERE b.locale="en_US" and animal.animal_id = b.animal_id))
    FROM animal 
    WHERE animal.locale = "de_DE";
```

You were not filtering on the animal id on the IFNULL select.  Basically, the IFNULL(..., ...) checks to see if a value is null and then will run the other query in its place.  From the documentation:

> The ifnull() function returns a copy of its first non-NULL argument, or NULL if both arguments are NULL. Ifnull() must have exactly 2 arguments. The ifnull() function is equivalent to coalesce() with two arguments.

Comment: This is called a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).